# compile RViz or ros_gui: python-qt-bindings missing

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile `ros_gui` or `rviz` on Xubuntu 11.10 within current *electric*, but without any success.

I did the usual clone for rviz, and a `roslocate info` with `rosinstall` for ros_gui. Everywhere the package or rosdep `python-qt-bindings` is referenced, but apart from [this kforge project](https://kforge.ros.org/projects/visualization/services/python_qt_binding/) it's kind of [inexistent](http://www.ros.org/search/index.html?cx=013029357434904786434%3Aafn5eukzpgg&cof=FORID%3A11%3BNB%3A1&ie=UTF-8&filter=0&num=10&input=python_qt_binding&q=python_qt_binding+more%3Aros_wiki_docs&sa=Submit). And it does not work. What have I done wrong?

Maybe this output helps:

```
$ rosdep satisfy rviz
Failed to find rosdep libqt4-dev for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep qt4-qmake for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep libqt4-opengl-dev for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep python-qt-bindings for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
error in processing scripts ABORTING: Rosdeps [u'libqt4-dev', u'qt4-qmake', u'libqt4-opengl-dev', u'python-qt-bindings'] could not be resolved
Failed to find rosdep libqt4-dev for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep qt4-qmake for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep libqt4-opengl-dev for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep python-qt-bindings for package rviz on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
The following rosdeps are not installed but are required [u'libqt4-dev', u'qt4-qmake', u'libqt4-opengl-dev', u'python-qt-bindings']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29120/compile-rviz-or-ros_gui:-python-qt-bindings-missing/) by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Fuerte versions of RViz and ros_gui both depend on the new little stack called python_qt_binding.  There only exists a Fuerte version of python_qt_binding, it did not exist in Electric.

So if you are trying to build the latest rviz and ros_gui code (Fuerte versions) under Electric, it just won't work.

However, Fuerte is coming along pretty well these days, we are close to releasing it.  If you do

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-visualization
```

you should get the latest Fuerte version of rviz, already compiled and everything.

Fuerte has a number of important differences from Electric.  See http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte.  As ever, you will need to source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash after installing and before doing

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

If you have other software which is not ready to build or run in Fuerte, you can still run rviz in a Fuerte-ized shell and run your Electric software in an Electric-ized shell.  Since ROS communication is serialized between processes, as long as the message definitions are the same on both sides, it works fine.  Most ROS messages that I've dealt with lately have not changed between Electric and Fuerte, so I think it is a pretty viable way to proceed.

It is true that we still have more work to do documenting the python_qt_binding package, sorry that is confusing.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-03-08**:
Oh, hadn't thought of that. *But*, I was trying electrics rviz, which did not work. Oh! I chose the `trunk` URL from the wiki, `tags/electric` is building fine. The same with the rviz from `/opt/`. But now I can test the new rviz. :)